# Can iPhone 6[OS 9.2] be automated using SFSafariViewController,appium & Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: iphone, macos, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am new to SFSafariViewController. I worked with ios-webkit-proxy & appium using selenium webdriver for iPhone 6[OS 9.2] automation. I just wanted to know whether we can automate a web application in iPhone using SFSafariViewController.!!!

Regards,
Nikhil V

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Appium works with native apps, hybrid apps and websites. So testing on SFSafariViewControllers is perfectly achievable.

The only requirement to test an app is that you have the .ipa or the .app of that app.

Hope this helps,
Liam

Comment: Hi @Liam, I need to automate a web application in safari browser in iPhone. Earlier I used ios-webkit-proxy to launch my web application in safari browser in iPhone. Now I want to do the same with SFSafariViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be automated for that you need a debug build n specify the bundle id of the app.
specify the path for ios debug kit
Mac OS X 10.7 or higher, 10.9.2 recommended
XCode >= 4.6.3, 5.1.1 recommended